# Question on exact differential equations: how do we know $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My text states that an exact differential equation is one for which $$
du \triangleq M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0.
$$
And from this it follows that $$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = M(x,y)~\text{ and }~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = N(x,y).
$$
which seems to imply that $$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dy} = 0.
$$
I assume this last point follows from the definition of $du$ above but I don't see how.

Comment: You really need to write $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and not regular derivatives. Note that you can rewrite your differential equation as $M(x,y) + N(x,y)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$, so $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$ on solution curves of the differential equation. I don't know where you're getting $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin. The difference between $\partial x$ and $dx$ has never been clearly articulated to me. And most references on differentials are quite baffling.

Comment: The partial derivative symbol is *always* used when you have a function of several variables and you differentiate with respect to one variable, *fixing the others*. I don't know your background, but the right context to understand "differentials" really is to learn about differential forms. This is beyond the usual calculus/multivariable calculus course.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin. I am new to differential equations. My text mentions $\partial u/ \partial x=M(x,y)$ which I sloppily read as $du/dx=M(x,y)$, causing my confusion. I understand partials quite well and am starting to come to grips with the total derivative -- which acts like the partial derivative in the single variable case. I don't have a great grasp of the rules for algebraically manipulating differentials and partials. And differential forms are beyond me until I finish diff eqns and multivariable analysis. Any good references on this topic (manipulating and understanding differentials)?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I sloppily read $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=M(x,y)$ as $\frac{du}{dx}=M(x,y)$ which caused my confusion. Because in this case, we would have
\begin{align}
du = M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy ~~\text{ and }~~~ \frac{du}{dx} = M(x,y)
\end{align}
and therefore that $$
N(x,y)dy = 0 ~\text{ which implies that }~ N(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0.
$$
And assuming $N(x,y) \not= 0$, this means $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$.